# How to remove ui-check class from div placed around Checkbox by jQuery

Tags: jquery, html, checkbox

Let me explain the problem with code. This is my HTML code:

```
<div class="badge" style="color:#ffffff">
     <p>Save Password to Phone?</p>
     <input type="checkbox" id="passwordremember"/>
</div>
```

But the jQuery Mobile frame work places a div around the check box with the following style `.ui-checkbox`. i.e:

```
<div class="ui-checkbox">
   <input type="checkbox" id="passwordremember"/>
</div>
```

Now saying `$("#passwordremember").removeClass("ui-checkbox")` wont work because the style is placed on the div. My question now is how do I remove the style from the div?

Comment: The better question is *why* you want to remove the class (your expression "remove the *style*" here is quite telling), anticipating that the real goal is better served by doing something else.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The answer to your question:

```
$("#passwordremember").closest(".ui-checkbox").removeClass("ui-checkbox");
```

http://api.jquery.com/closest/

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
$("#passwordremember").parent().removeClass("ui-checkbox");
```

The above code will check parent node and remove the class `ui-checkbox`